# Do multiple Captain Marvels work together?

Tags: marvel-snap

In Marvel Snap, the card Captain Marvel has an ability which lets her move to a new location after the last turn if doing so would cause you to win the game. There are also several ways to get two copies of the same card in play at once; we won't worry about which one was used.

Suppose the board is in this state:

- All three locations are ruins (or other locations with no relevant effects)
- No other effects change the power of any cards in play
- the opponent's cards at each location are Giganto, Misty Knight, Abomination
- Your cards at each location are Captain Marvel, Captain Marvel + Shocker, Nothing.

As a result, your opponent's powers are 14, 2, 9 while your powers are 6, 9, 0 and you lose left and right. Neither of your copies of Captain Marvel can *individually* move in a way that would lead to a win. However, if *both* Captain Marvels move to the right location then your powers become 0, 3, 12 and you win middle and right.

If this situation occurred, would the two copies of Captain Marvel both move to the right in order to secure victory, or would they each remain stationary due to their abilities being resolved separately?

Answer (score 3):

Based on times I've seen Captain Marvel move when my opponent was losing all three locations, I don't think, contrary to her card text, she moves in order to "win the game."  Rather, she moves in order to win a *location* if moving doesn't change the outcome of the location she's on.

Therefore, in your scenario, neither one would move.  Poor Carol just can't think that far ahead.